# Find character encoding of uploaded CSV file

Tags: java, spring, character-encoding

I have situation where I can upload a CSV file through UI, and at server side I am using `CommonsMultipartResolver` of Spring to convert that uploaded CSV into an `InputStream`. How can I identify what encoding the uploaded CSV file is in?

Answer (score 0):

In plain java you cannot do this. But there are some third party libarys like

- [GuessEncoding](https://github.com/codehaus/guessencoding)
- [juniversalchardet](https://github.com/thkoch2001/juniversalchardet)

these are able to get the file encoding. In GuessEncoding it would be simply

```
Charset cs = CharsetToolkit.guessEncoding(file, 4096, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```